# dropbox oauth2 - redirect to dropbox developer docs

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, dropbox

I use stevenmaguire/oauth2-dropbox library for oauth2.

When i try to go to oauth2 url: https://api.dropbox.com/oauth2/authorize?state=&token_access_type=offline&scope=&response_type=code&redirect_uri=<redirect_uri>&client_id=<client_id> - i get the redirect to https://www.dropbox.com/developers.

What is the reason of such behavior? And how can i get the token instead of redirect to dropbox docs?

Answer (score 0):

[The Dropbox /oauth2/authorize page](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#oauth2-authorize) should be accessed on [www.dropbox.com](http://www.dropbox.com), not api.dropbox.com. (Attempting to access it on api.dropbox.com results in that redirect.)